# How to checkout multiple tfs folders in a single pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, plugins, tfs, jenkins-pipeline, checkout

Let's assume there is a TFS Repository

http://tfstta.example.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/

and assume there are five folders in that repository

**Folder1,
Folder2,
Folder3,
Folder4,
Folder5**

In Jenkins using TFS Plugin I can configure like below to clone single folder from repository,

[Here is single folder cloaning configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvzJk.png) (**Please view it**)

**How can I clone multiple folders at a time?**

Comment: Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally [This Code worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKygw.png), Thanks everyone who responded.

Now I can use this code multiple times in a single groovy file by changing the project path.

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'PASSWORD-FORMASTAPPS', variable: 'PASSWORD')]) 
{
    checkout([$class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm',
    projectPath: '$/***Folder1 path***', 
    serverUrl: 'http://example1.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection', 
    useOverwrite: true, 
    useUpdate: true, 
    userName: 'TEN\\Uxxxxxxx', 
    password: hudson.util.Secret.fromString(PASSWORD),
    workspaceName: 'Hudson-${JOB_NAME}-${NODE_NAME}'])
    echo password
}

withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'PASSWORD-FORMASTAPPS', variable: 'PASSWORD')]) 
{
    checkout([$class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm',
    projectPath: '$/***Folder2 path***', 
    serverUrl: 'http://example1.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection', 
    useOverwrite: true, 
    useUpdate: true, 
    userName: 'TEN\\Uxxxxxxx', 
    password: hudson.util.Secret.fromString(PASSWORD),
    workspaceName: 'Hudson-${JOB_NAME}-${NODE_NAME}'])
    echo password
}
```

Comment: After the second checkout, first checkout folder seems to be cleared.. if I use 'useUpdate', second checkout is not gettting all the files

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below structure for pipeline multiple checkouts:**

```
stages 
{
    stage("GIT-Checkout") 
    {
        steps 
        {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '<PARAM>']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: '<PARAM>', relativeTargetDir: '<PARAM>', timeout: 20 ]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<PARAM>', url: '<PARAM>']]])
        } // steps
    } // stage

    stage("GIT-Checkout2") 
    {
        steps 
        {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '<PARAM>']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: '<PARAM>', relativeTargetDir: '<PARAM>', timeout: 20 ]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<PARAM>', url: '<PARAM>']]])
        } // steps
    } // stage

    stage("GIT-Checkout3") 
    {
        steps 
        {
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '<PARAM>']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: '<PARAM>', relativeTargetDir: '<PARAM>', timeout: 20 ]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '<PARAM>', url: '<PARAM>']]])
        } // steps
    } // stage
} //Stages

*Replace <PARAM> with the required values
```

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Kulkarni, Thanks for the quick response, but I am looking for TFS Cloning process.

Comment: its the similar structure for TFS @PavanKumarChithari.. just use pipeline syntax to format for TFS and implement the same.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but if you can see the snippet of code in a question is generated using **Pipeline Syntax generator** only, first snippet is with **autocredentials** and second one is with **mannualcredentials**, auto credentials code is giving **Query returned no result**, and in mannualcredentials code how to pass **hudson.util.secret** as a parameter to password. just "checkout scm"  is cloning the folder, but I need multiple folders for that I am trying to go with script.             I Hope you understand what I am facing here

Answer (score 0):

You may check the following code:

```
checkout([$class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm', 
credentialsConfigurer: [$class: 'AutomaticCredentialsConfigurer'], 
projectPath: '$/ProcessControlSystems/RSBatch', 
serverUrl: 'http://tfstta.example.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection',  
useOverwrite: true, 
useUpdate: true, 
workspaceName: 'Hudson-${JOB_NAME}-${NODE_NAME}'])
```

Comment: Same  error I am getting :---                                                                                        
                                                                                                                               
 14:16:14 Querying for remote changeset at '$/ProcessControlSystems/RSBatch' as of 'D2020-03-03T08:46:12Z'...                                                                                                     
14:16:16 Query returned no result!

Comment: If use `projectPath: '$/TFS/Server_Path', serverUrl: 'http://tfs-server-url/',`, how's the result?

Comment: **Are you saying like this? projectPath: '$/TFS/ProcessControlSystems/RSBatch'   which is also not working**

Comment: How about `checkout([$class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm', localPath: 'D:\\BUILD-Code-scm', projectPath: '$/ROOTDIR/Modules', serverUrl: 'http://XXX>XXX.com:8080/tfs/ROOTDIR', useOverwrite: true, useUpdate: true, userName: 'TLR\\UNMAE', password: hudson.util.Secret.fromString('PASSWORD'), workspaceName: 'Hudson-${JOB_NAME}-${NODE_NAME}'])`?

Comment: Thank you @Cece Dong